# Finding cells with particular font (example Bold) and copy that cell value in the cells below it

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose there is a report where the output is like this.

**Falkon**

```
123
1234
233
22
```

**Frosty**

```
12
23
```

**Dafren**

```
12
335
33
```

Now is there anyway in VBA where I can find the values of bold cells ,copy them and paste them in the numeric figures after them till the next bold cell.

Like I want to copy Falkon and paste it in the 4 cells next to it, then I wanna copy Frosty and paste in the two cells next to it and so on.
[Image of the excel is attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9SNV.png)

Comment: Is the data in your actual workbook exactly same as you have shown in the sample image? i.e. a bold text followed by some numeric values and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub FillCells()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A2:A" & lr).Value = Range("A2:A" & lr).Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub brb()
    Dim MaxRows, i As Integer
    MaxRows = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    For i = 0 To MaxRows - 1
        If Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold = False Then
            Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
            Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: excellent!!! can you please explain? This part.
 If Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold Then
            pasteContents = Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
        Else
            Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = pasteContents
            Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold = True

Comment: What is the difference when paste contents is used in begining (pasteContents = Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value)
and when its used at end ( Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = pasteContents)

Comment: This is genius! Cant find these in youtube.
This is not coding, this is art ! 
Thank you